# How to give SVG circle a stroke according to the values from database?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, svg

[image]PHP Values

```
$total_hours = 10; 
$used_hours = 4; 
$remaining_hours = 6;
```

HTML

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" 
     fill="transparent" />
```

Now how can I give the circle dynamic stroke based on php values ?
Thanks, and sorry I am totally new to web development.
OR how to do this with circle progress bar (see the attachment example please)

Comment: Not really, I want to display three colors on circle based on three value like $user_hour= 4 now the 40% of circle color would be e.g red and rest of 60% would be e.g green

Comment: Are you talking about three differently colored circle segments, or what? If so, how are the PHP values you have shown related to this?

Comment: yes, exactly I want to display three different color segments on circle

Comment: Then _start_ by doing your own proper research, what the SVG to achieve this in a static variant should look like. Making this dynamic with your PHP variable values, would be the second step.

Comment: If you need to display three different color segments you will need 3 circles

Comment: As enxaneta said: you need 2 circles as in my solution below. It's not possible to have solid gradient arcs of a circle with SVG 1.1 (supporting only linear and radial gradients) so visualization libraries like D3.js solve that with calculating arcs e.g. "slices".

But it will be possible to separate arcs with solid colors and thus use only one SVG circle for this using so called conic gradients that should be supported in SVG 2 (when web browsers support them as well, there are workarounds currently for that).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Without going to more advanced code (but simpler to create your "donut" arc, e.g. using D3.js library etc) you can solve this with javascript and basic SVG:

```
<?php
$total_hours = 10; 
$used_hours = 4; 
$remaining_hours = 6;
?>

<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="3" 
     fill="transparent" />  
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" 
     fill="transparent" />
</svg>
<script>
    var path = document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[1];
    var length = path.getTotalLength();
    var total_hours = <?php echo $total_hours ?>;
    var used_hours = <?php echo $used_hours ?>;
    var remaining_hours = <?php echo $remaining_hours ?>;

    var ratio = used_hours/total_hours;
    var used_path_length = (1-ratio) * length;
    path.setAttribute("style", "stroke-dasharray: " + length + "; stroke-dashoffset: " + used_path_length);
    path.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(-90, 50, 50)");
</script>
```

Red circle is drawn on top of the green (SVG doesn't have z-index as HTML5 DOM e.g. what get drawn last is put on top of all previous objects). And then its (stroked) path length is adjusted based on your variables.

For clarity it would be enough just to have total and used hours (as variables).

Comment: Thank You for your help, I had managed to draw it by using https://github.com/lugolabs/circles. Simple and easy solution.

Comment: Sure, that works too. And you know how to initialize javascript variables with PHP variable values.

It would be nice to mark the answer as useful since I haven't used any library (I have created my own jQuery animated "counters" in the past similar as your library used).